# Inflate an XML in Fragment programmatically

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, layout-inflater

I have `MainActivity.java` as my first Fragment and the another Fragment being `Fragment.java` having a TabHost in it. When user clicks on a button in MainActivity, I want to inflate an XML in second fragment's Tab1.

`OnClickListener` of the Button in `MainActivity` is as follows:

```
btOkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        LayoutInflater lf = getLayoutInflater();
        Fragment.updateTab1(lf);                
    }               
});
```

And `updateTab1(..)` method in Fragment class is:

```
public static void updateTab1(LayoutInflater lf) {
        lf.inflate(R.layout.xml_to_inflate, (ViewGroup)llTab1, false);
    }
```

Where:

```
llTab1 = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tab1);
```

---

I am not getting any Exception while doing this, nor Force Close.

In Debug I can see all of this code run without any exception but no required XML being inflated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Finally what worked for me:

As working with fragments I had missed following line in *onCreate()* to make the *inflater* object work:

`inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();`

and keeping the rest of code as it is.